# Finding the width of Cars using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect the width (in pixels) of any car in front of me. So, I tried to extract the horizontal lines which is supposed to correspond to its width. Below is my approach:

input image :

[image]

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

import numpy as np

from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

image = cv2.imread('croopped.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 250, apertureSize=3)

cv2_imshow(edges)
```

[image]

```
kernel = np.ones((1,5))
linh = cv2.erode(edges,kernel)
cv2_imshow(linh)
```

[image]

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(linh, 1, np.pi/180, 10, maxLineGap= 50, minLineLength = 50)

if lines is not None:
  for line in lines:
      x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
      cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2_imshow(image)
```

[image]

As you can see the lines are not as expected (to get a good horizontal line corresponds to its width)
expected results:

[image]

How can I fine tune/use different approach to get better horizontal lines?

Comment: even if you could get the exact line, just measuring the length of the line would assume that the car is perpendicular to the view, which is clearly not. You would need to consider the angle of the car. It would actually be easier to identify the model of the car and get the dimensions from the car technical specifications.

Comment: I don't see a place where you can measure the width with some accuracy, and certainly not in an automatic way ! Even a human would fail. Taking 3/4 of the image width will be as good.

Comment: **Canny** certainly will only ruin everything here. don't use it for anything. -- just use an object detection neural network and analyze the inferred bounding boxes. you can even train a network to infer a car's width. it'll learn car brands and models and just tell you the numbers from the spec sheets that were hopefully used for training. for anything it doesn't specifically know, it might use the entire picture and guesstimate the 3D position and scale of whatever car there is...

Answer (score 1):

You can try getting the vertical lines instead, and then measure their distance as shown in the code:

```py
kernel = np.ones((1,5))
linh = cv2.erode(edges,kernel)
cv2_imshow(linh)
```

Not sure how you would modify the code for that case though.

Comment: You might show how the vertical lines would look?

Comment: you've got the input picture. you can produce those vertical lines yourself. no need to ask OP for this. -- how do you imagine that going much better than what OP already has? the car has multiple vertical lines that don't belong to its back face.